# android implement database checker method in Service

Tags: android

how can I implement the following method in Service , I want it to work every 1 min
(the code is check day hour mint if corresponding to current time do some thing  ) I saw many questions
but not useful ,help please . Thank you

{String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_chNAME, KEY_prNAME,
                KEY_Rerun, KEY_HOUR, KEY_MINUTE, KEY_SUN, KEY_MON, KEY_TUE,
                KEY_WED, KEY_THU, KEY_FRI, KEY_SAT };
        Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null, null);
        String result = "";

```
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // String mStr="";
    // mStr=mStr.concat("<body>");
    // mStr=mStr.concat("<table border='1' ><tr> <th style='width:5px></th><td align='center'><b> Channal  </b></td><td align='center'><b>  Program  </b></td><td align='center'><b>  Time  </b></tr>");
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iCh = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_chNAME);
    int ipr = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_prNAME);
    int iHr = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOUR);
    int iMin = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MINUTE);
    int iRerun = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Rerun);
    int iSun = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUN);
    int iMon = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MON);
    int iTue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TUE);
    int iWed = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WED);
    int iThu = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_THU);
    int iFri = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FRI);
    int iSat = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAT);

    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat( "00" );

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iSun))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMon))) {

            //int mm=Integer.parseInt( twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))));

            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iTue))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin)))+ "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iWed))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iThu))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iFri))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    + twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }

        else if (today == Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iSat))) {
            result += c.getString(iRow) + " - " + c.getString(iCh) + "\t  "
                    + c.getString(ipr) + "\t " + c.getString(iHr) + ":"
                    +twoDigits.format(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMin))) + "  " + c.getString(iRerun) + "\n";
        }
    }
    c.close(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of AlarmManager + IntentService.

With alarm manager you can schedule events. IntentServices are services that perform one shot tasks in a background thread. Their combination is the more straightforward way to perform scheduled jobs.

Check for example [this](http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/) post